# two premises with four conclusions drawn from them (taking singly or together). Which conclusions are validly drawn?

Tags: logic

```
 Given below are two premises with four conclusions drawn from them (taking singly or 
  together). Which conclusions are validly drawn ? Select the correct answer from the code 
  given below. 

  Premises :  (i) All lawyers are extroverts.
              (ii) Some wisemen are extroverts.
  Conclusions : (a) All lawyers are wisemen.
              (b) All wisemen are lawyers.
              (c) Some extroverts are wisemen.
              (d) All extroverts are lawyers.
  Code :

 (1) (b) and (c) only
 (2) (c) only
 (3) (a) only
 (4) (a) and (c) only
```

I guess the correct answer is option 2, which is some extroverts are wisemen. isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct. You can visualize this via a Venn diagram. Let $L$ be the set of all lawyers, let $E$ be the set of all extroverts, and let $W$ be the set of all wisemen. Then the first premise states that $L$ is a subset of $E$ (i.e.: $L$ is contained in $E$), and the second premise states that $E$ and $W$ overlap (i.e.: there is at least one person who is both an extrovert and a wiseman).

Conclusion (a) could be false, since $L$ doesn't need to be contained in $W$ (i.e.: there could be some person who is a lawyer but not a wiseman). You can reason similarly for the other two wrong conclusions.